# Moving drawing in canvas android

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to move drawing in the canvas. I have the working code but the problem is that when I click on the canvas to drag for the second time it resets itself to its initial position (its default position) n then again starts moving. I want it to move from where I have left on my first drag.

In my code of custom view I have a function called setupCoordinates where the coordinates of my drawings are initialized. (x and y, I am using it to move the drawings. These values are update by the onTouch Listener of my activity)

I am adding my view to a relative layout as

```
relLay.addView(custView);
```

There is a onTouch Listener to my layout

```
relLay.setOntouchListener(touch);
```

And in my touch listener I am updating my drawing by passing evet.getX() and event.getY()

```
custView.setXY(evet.getX(), event.getY());
```

Below is the code of my custom view where i am drawing :

```
public CustView(Context context) {
    super(context);
            setupDrawing();
            setupCoordinates();
}

private void setupDrawing() {
    path = new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    borderPaint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    borderPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

private void setupCoordinates() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    top = 150 ;
    right = 450 ;
    left = 200 ;
    bottom = 400 ;
    linex = 120;
    liney = 300;
    openSize = 20;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
        path.reset();
        mCanvas = canvas;

         rectf = new RectF(left+x, top+y, right+x, bottom+y);
         rect = rectf;
         int angle = (int) angle(new Point((getWidth())/2, (getHeight())/2), new Point(linex,liney)); 


        int startAngle = angle + (openSize/2);
        int sweepAngle = 360 - openSize;

        path.arcTo(rectf, startAngle, sweepAngle);
        path.lineTo(linex, liney);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, borderPaint);

}

public void setXY(int dx, int dy){
    x = dx;
    y = dy;
    invalidate();
}

private double angle(Point point1, Point point2) {
    double deltaX = (point1.x - point2.x);
    double deltaY = (point1.y - point2.y);
    double angle =  Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360;
    }

    if (angle > 360) {
        angle -= 360;
    }
    // Compensate for 0
    angle -= 180;
    return angle;
}
```

Can any one tell me why is it resetting to its initial position when I drag it for the second time ?

I am also open to other methods on moving the drawings inside of canvas, if there is any please let me know. I dont want to move the view or canvas only the drawing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When are you calling setupCoordinates()?

Comment: In onCreate() of my Custom View

Comment: @Niko when we call invalidate() it only calls onDraw() right ?

Comment: Yes, how and when are you initializing the Path?

Comment: @Niko I have updated my Cust View class in my question both the coordinates and path I am initializing in my onCreate method.

Comment: Can you also add the angle method, I try the code myself to see how it works

Comment: @Niko i hv added it. n thanks for helping out

Comment: Okay, so when the view gets setXY called, it calls the draw and the line is drawn based on those x-y values. Let's say the line is horizontal angle and you press up, then press down on bottom so it's snaps into vertical angle and you want that angle change to be smooth like user would have dragged it there instead of snapping?

Comment: Not exactly, the dragging is happenning smooth. problem is - when i drag for the second time my drawing goes to its initial position n then starts to move. lets say on my first drag x value changes to 50 so accordingly my left (200) and right (450) value changes n my drawing shifts to 50 + in x direction. when i drag for second time the drawing goes back to its initial pos left (200) and right (450) and then moves

Comment: That's weird, your code behaves following way with me: DOWN event snaps the drawing position, MOVE event smooth draws it based on x,y and UP event also. Then I press again DOWN it snaps into drawing position and works same way than the first time.

Comment: Is it working fine on ACTION MOVE of touch listener ?

Comment: Yes it's working normally, maybe I'm not understanding your problem here or there's some bug somewhere in your code which I don't have when I copied your code.

Comment: I am having too many custviews added in my layout. I am also trying to determine which drawing is being clicked. May be i am doing some silly mistake. I will re check my code again. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: can u post ur onTouch listener code in ans section below?

Comment: @Niko ok there was a mistake in my onTouch listener. Now i am getting the same thing as you. When I click on the bubble it first snaps to a pos n then moves smoothly. any idea on how to avoid the snapping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample how to avoid snapping, with tweaking the values it should work:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    mCustomView.setXYAnimated((int) event.getX(),
            (int) event.getY());
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    mCustomView.setXY((int) event.getX(),
            (int) event.getY());
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    mCustomView.setXY((int) event.getX(),
            (int) event.getY());
    break;
}
```

In custom view:

```
private int x = -1;
private int y = -1;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

public void setXY(int dx, int dy) {
    if (mCountDownTimer == null) {
        x = dx;
        y = dy;

        invalidate();
    }
}

public void setXYAnimated(final int newX, final int newY) {
    if (x == -1 && y == -1) {
        setXY(newX, newY);
    } else {
        if (mCountDownTimer == null) {
            final int time = 250;

            mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time, 10) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    float progress = 1 - ((float) millisUntilFinished / time);

                    int x2, y2;

                    if (x < newX) {
                        x2 = (int) (x + (progress * (newX - x)));
                    } else {
                        x2 = (int) (x - (progress * (x - newX)));
                    }

                    if (y < newY) {
                        y2 = (int) (y + (progress * (newY - y)));
                    } else {
                        y2 = (int) (y - (progress * (y - newY)));
                    }

                    x = x2;
                    y = y2;

                    postInvalidate();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mCountDownTimer = null;

                    setXY(newX, newY);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```